# open xml urls with firefox quantum

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-quantum

Since firefox 57 I cannot open xml files anymore: while old firefoxes renders the xmls showing the structure reindenting e formatting the source, now I see a blank page.

Yes, I know I can show the sources and access the "raw" xml, but it's all in one line, and, basically, unreadable.

I searched but I didn't find any extension; is there a way (some usersite css?) to show xml files in firefox?